# Vee-validate Validate only some fields

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

I have in a form multiple inputs that are validated by vee-validate, it works well, but I want to only check some fields on an event. So after seeing one issue about this https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/issues/1089, I wrote this function:

```
       async checkInputs(){
            let inputs = ['input1', 'input2', 'input3', 'input4'];
            const results = Promise.all(
                inputs.map(input => {
                    if(this.$validator.validate(input) === true)
                        null;
                    else
                        dictionary.custom[input].required();
                })
            );

            return (await results).filter(element => element != null);
        }
```

The idea is to get an array with the error messages of the fields that failed. Note that I used some console.log to be sure that when the check of the input fails, it returns the error message. But when I use it:

```
           this.checkInputs().then(function(results) {
                console.log(results);
            });
```

I only have an array with 4 undefined values instead of an array of 4 strings for the errors messages.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `$nextTick`?

```
  this.$nextTick(function() {
        this.checkInputs().then(function(results) {
            console.log(results);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.map()` should return value, also `this.$validator.validate(input)` return promise, so you could wrote something like this:

```
inputs.map(async input => {
   if(await this.$validator.validate(input) === true)
     return null;
   else
     return dictionary.custom[input].required();
   })
```